# KeyboardEvent Listener causing TypeError?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5, package

I'm getting this weird error, don't know why, I've reduced the code to minimum and found the source of the problem but I don't understand why it errors.

Main.as

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class main extends MovieClip{
        public function main(){
            var player1 = new playerTest( 100 , 275 );
            addChild( player1 );
        }
    }
}
```

Player.as

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

    public class playerTest extends MovieClip{
        public function playerTest(xCoord:int, yCoord:int){
            x = xCoord;
            y = yCoord;
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownEvent);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpEvent);
        }
        private function keyDownEvent(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
            //
        }
        private function keyUpEvent(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
            //
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment out either of the KeyboardEvent listeners then it works fine, but just having them there like that makes it error and returns

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at playerTest()
    at main()
```

This only has started happening since I converted my code to make my character be spawned through code instead of just throwing it onto the stage, when it was like that before it worked totally fine.

Comment: Are you sure the stage is not null ? Check this http://www.redcodelabs.com/2009/07/flex-null-stage/    maybe you should use this.systemManager.stage instead.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you can access stage from any DisplayObject that is already on the stage. So, in your class, you can wait till the player is added to the stage to add the keyboard listeners, like this:

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

public class playerTest extends MovieClip{
    public function playerTest(xCoord:int, yCoord:int){
        x = xCoord;
        y = yCoord;
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);

    }
    private function init(e:Event)
    {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownEvent);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpEvent);
    }
    private function keyDownEvent(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
        //
    }
    private function keyUpEvent(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
        //
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what Benny says, you can absolutely use the stage from an external class, however that class must be a (or a subclass of a) DisplayObject that is also -on- the stage. As player1 is instantiated and then added to the stage, it does not yet have a reference to the stage. You can listen for Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE and then hookup your events to the stage if you'd like.

Comment: S. If the external class do not have any reference to displayObject?

Comment: If it is the document class isn't it already on stage? Been a long time since I played with flash I do mostly flex and I just do not remember lol.

Comment: I do not ask about document class. An external class which is do not subclassed by any displayObjects?

Comment: In that case, you are best just adding stage:Stage as a parameter in the constructor, and passing a reference to stage in. In this case, you would do something more like BennyGeo's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a best practice to refer the `stage` from an external class, may be if you are not subclassing any `displayobject` that will not allow you to refer `stage`. So it is better to go with displayObjects.

```
package {
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
        import flash.display.DisplayObject;

        public class playerTest extends MovieClip{
            public function playerTest(xCoord:int, yCoord:int,_stage:DisplayObject){
                x = xCoord;
                y = yCoord;
                _stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownEvent);
                _stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpEvent);
            }
            private function keyDownEvent(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
                //
                trace("down");
            }
            private function keyUpEvent(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
                //
            }
        }
    }
```

//main

```
 package  {
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        public class main extends MovieClip{
            public function main(){
                var player1 = new playerTest( 100 , 275 ,stage);
                addChild( player1 );
            }
        }
    }
```